# Boolean Algebra: Is this equality or inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ring-theory, boolean-algebra

Consider: $$xy + x'y' + yz = xy + x'y' +x'z$$

Is this equality true?

I know I could a truth-table but I prefer doing it algebraically. I think there's something tricky here (Like adding a term, relying on the fact that $x+x = x$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No real tricks, but it does use $X + X = X$ (Idempotent) and $X + \bar X = 1$ (Complement).
$$xy + \bar x \bar y + yz = xy (\bar z + z) + \bar x \bar y(\bar z + z) + yz (\bar x + x)$$
Expand missing terms.
$$= xy\bar z + {\color{Red} {xyz}} + \bar x\bar y\bar z + \bar x\bar yz + \bar xyz + {\color{Red} {xyz}}$$
Remove duplicates.
$$= xy\bar z + xyz + \bar x\bar y\bar z + \bar x\bar yz + \bar xyz $$
Look for common terms - duplicate as needed - looking for $\bar xz$.

$$= (xy\bar z + xyz) + (\bar x\bar y\bar z + {\color{Red} {\bar x\bar yz}})  + (\bar xyz + {\color{Red} {\bar x \bar yz}}) \\ $$
$$= xy (\bar z + z) + \bar x\bar y (\bar z + z) + \bar xz (y + \bar y) $$

So they are equal.
$$xy + \bar x\bar y + yz = xy + \bar x\bar y + \bar xz$$

Comment: This answer might look nicer if you used some [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format it.

Comment: Nice solution! +1